# How to make a scroll to fixed div that doesn't stick to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fixed

I have a side bar like on this demo, that starts at a certain position on the page and as you scroll down it bounces a long with that position. I'd like something like that but without the bouncing.

http://blog.echoenduring.com/wp-content/uploads/demos/echo_ContainedStickyScroll/

The closest I have come are the other scroll to fixed position questions but I don't want my div to have to hit the top of the page to become fixed. How do I do this?

Comment: You should post sample code here (HTML, JS, whatever is relevant) as well as any code samples of what you have already tried. Links to JSFiddle, etc are also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check the scroll of the page :

```
if($(window).scrollTop() < somePosition) {
    $("mydiv").css("position","fixed");

}
```